# What do the 3-character aircraft type codes mean?

Tags: aircraft-identification, terminology

On some aircraft lists, including [Eurocontrol's Aircraft Performance Database](https://contentzone.eurocontrol.int/aircraftperformance/default.aspx), aircraft have a 3 character code as their type. For example, an Airbus A320neo has a type of "L2J", a Boeing 747-400 has a type of "L4J" and a Cessna 152 has a type of "L1P".

I'm guessing the 2nd character is the number of engines (although some aircraft have a C for the 2nd character, and I'm not sure what that means), and the 3rd character is the type of engine (e.g. P for Piston, J for jet and T for turbine).

I'm not sure what the first character represents.

There are 6 options for the first character: L, S, A, H, G and T.

Does anyone know how these codes work?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Those are **aircraft type descriptions,** and are covered by ICAO Doc 8643.

> The first symbol describes the aircraft type:
>
> - L - Landplane, e.g. A320. Note: A floatplane, which can temporarily be converted to a landplane or vice versa, is described as a landplane and not a seaplane or amphibian in ICAO Doc 8643.
> - S - Seaplane, e.g. HARBIN SH-5 (ICAO designator SH5)
> - A - Amphibian, e.g. LA4
> - G - Gyrocopter, e.g. A002
> - H - Helicopter, e.g. A109
> - T - Tiltrotor, e.g. V22
>
> The second symbol specifies the number of engines 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8 or C, where C means that two engines are coupled to drive a single propeller system (e.g. C08T). The C symbol is only used for fixed-wing aircraft.
>
> The third symbol specifies the engine type:
>
> - J - jet
> - T - turboprop/turboshaft
> - P - piston
> - E - electric
> - R - rocket

Source: [Aircraft Description (ICAO Doc 8643)](https://skybrary.aero/articles/aircraft-description-icao-doc-8643), skybrary.aero

---

For the FAA, they're broken down to **Aircraft Class** and **Aircraft Engine Number and Type,** followed by the **FAA Weight Class.** E.g. `Fixed-wing 2J/H`. (See [JO 7360.1 - Aircraft Type Designators](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1040302).)

Comment: Do dirigibles and blimps have a coding?

Comment: @RBarryYoung: they have a [special designator](https://www.icao.int/publications/DOC8643/Pages/SpecialDesignators.aspx): `SHIP`. And balloons get `BALL`. But no description codes further than that.

Comment: I guess it's a good thing there are no flyable B-36s: not only does it have too many engines, it has engines of mixed types.

Comment: Notable that the word Ballon is in fact derived from the word Ball, but this is the first time that I've seen it obvious in usage.